# Get function name to string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I  have a script which monitor a directory and call a function with certain arguments. And in this script a open file.log to explain what happened each time there is a new file in the monitored directory.

This is the prototype of my function :

```
def and_now_my_watch_begin(dir_to_watch, function_to_call, *args_for_function):
```

I would like to know if there was any way to get function's name like a function.name.to_str() or something like this ?

Comment: You know, there *is* a search function.

Comment: Ctrl-F? Up-up-down-down-left-right-left-right B-A-B-A? 
//*[@id="search"]/input ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, simply look into `__name__`:

```
>>> def foo(): pass
... 
>>> foo.__name__
'foo'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the __name__ attribute of the function. For example:

```
def function():
    return

print(function.__name__)
```

This will print:

```
'function'
```

Comment: Whoever downvoted my answer, please explain why so I can know where I have not succeeded in answering.